# Fatal: No such URL found when URL exists git

Tags: git, github

I want to change the git upstream repository but when I did the following command:

```
 git remote set-url --push django https://github.com/drobertazzi/django https://github.com/drobertazzi
```

I got `fatal: No such URL found: https://github.com/drobertazzi` when said link clearly exists. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using this form of [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
```

Note that `<oldurl>` is optional, but you have provided it. Let's see how `set-url` works:

> `set-url`
>
> Changes URL remote points to. Sets first URL remote points to matching regex `<oldurl>` (first URL if no `<oldurl>` is given) to `<newurl>`. If `<oldurl>` doesn’t match any URL, error occurs and nothing is changed.

That last sentence is important. If `<oldurl>` doens't match a URL that `<name>` already contains in your remote configuration, you'll get the error that you currently see.

In most cases remotes only have a single URL, so you can safely omit `<oldurl>`. Try this instead:

```
git remote set-url --push django https://github.com/drobertazzi/django
```